# Jenkins HTML Publisher Plugin : allow script permission issue

Tags: jenkins, content-security-policy

I'm trying to report my `.html` file with HTML publisher plugin in Jenkins
however,since HTML publisher is updated to version 1.10, can't publish HTML.

**Error message I'm getting:**

```
Blocked script execution in '{mydomain}' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.

Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.
```

I found this doc:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy

It tells about CSP.

**I run Jenkins with arg :**

```
/usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=sandbox allow-scripts; style-src 'unsafe-inline' *;script-src 'unsafe-inline' *; -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1
```

but still got same error above.

**what i tried args :**

```
 1. -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="sandbox; default-src 'self';"
 2. -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=
 3. -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="sandbox; default-src *;"
 4. -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="sandbox allow-scripts; default-src *;"
```

**.html is located in :**

```
{mydomain}/job/{job_name}/Doc/index.html
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you have a try with a blank CSP option?

```
/usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP= -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1
```

On my Jenkins instance, it solved my reporting issues.

I know it's not a safe option, but I didn't find another solution :(

Comment: i solve this. your answer is right but should remove browser cache additionally, thank you

Answer (score 20):

I faced similar issue I found and applied following solution:

**Steps:**

1. Go to the Jenkins Admin page (login as admin).
2. Go to Manage Jenkins ->  Script Console
3. Then in the script console copy paste following it made it work

**Snippet**: `System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-scripts; default-src *; style-src * http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'");`

This [link](https://content-security-policy.com/#source_list) provides more details on each of the parameters that we have set in the above code line.

Note for **Persistency in jenkins configuration**:
@RayKim mentioned this is not a sustainable change. If you want to keep this change permanently then in that case you should set this property values up in the `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.remoting.Launcher.pingIntervalSec=0"`

After setting this variable you have to restart your `Jenkins` to load the new configuration.

Comment: important to note that this does NOT survive upon a restart. To make it permanent, update the "JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS" inside of (/etc/sysconfig/jenkins for CentOS) while other distros it may be inside (/etc/default/jenkins)

Answer (score 2):

For me above didn't work;

I tried this

Manage Jenkins -> Script Console
Copy-paste this

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")
```

For permanent solution:
Add the following to JAVA_ARGS under /etc/default/jenkins:

```
-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=""
```

Comment: how to load images. it does not help with png images