# Why does only instruction coverage appear in the JaCoCo Jenkins report?

Tags: java, jenkins, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a Java project for which I want to see automated test coverage in Jenkins builds.

For this purpose I modified the files as shown below.

`Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Test") {
            steps {
                sh 'cat settings_default.xml'
                sh 'mvn -gs settings_default.xml test'
            }
        }
        stage("Test Reports") {
            steps {
                jacoco(
                        execPattern: 'target/*.exec',
                        classPattern: 'target/classes',
                        sourcePattern: 'src/main/java',
                        exclusionPattern: 'src/test*',
                        changeBuildStatus: true,
                        runAlways: true,
                        minimumBranchCoverage: '60'
                )
            }
        }
        stage("Build") {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -gs settings_default.xml package'
            }
         }
    }
}
```

`pom.xml`: Added following fragment to `build/plugins`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/configuration/*.*</exclude>
            <exclude>**/model/*</exclude>
            <exclude>**/MyApplication.*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>check-coverage</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <rule>
                        <element>CLASS</element>
                        <limits>
                            <limit>
                                <counter>LINE</counter>
                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                <minimum>0.80</minimum>
                            </limit>
                            <limit>
                                <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                <minimum>0.80</minimum>
                            </limit>
                        </limits>
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I run the Jenkins job, I only see the instruction coverage in the report:

[image: Screenshot of a Jenkins build with only instruction coverage being displayed]

**What do I need to change and where (`pom.xml`, `Jenkinsfile`, Jenkins configuration on the server, something else) in order to see the branch and class coverage as well?**

**Update 1:** Adding

```
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.6</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>report</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

to `pom.xml` did not solve the problem.

Comment: What Jenkins version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error was the fact that this was a multi-module Maven project with two different `pom.xml`. The Jenkins report was being generated for a module (subdirectory) and one of the steps was configured wrongly (the configuration pointed to the wrong directory).

```
        stage("Test Reports") {
            steps {
                dir('my-module') {
                    jacoco( 
[...]
```

Surrounding the `jacoco` statement with `dir('my-module') { [...] }` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To see the complete jacoco report, I would use the HTML Publisher plugin.

First, you need to configure the pom.xml file to generate the jacoco coverage report, adding the following plugin.

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- attached to Maven test phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Then, after running `mvn install` command, the jacoco report will be generated in the directory target/site/jacoco/index.html.

Now you have to configure Jenkins to show this report. So, the next step is to install the [HTML Publisher plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/htmlpublisher/) in Jenkins. You can use the plugin manager to do this task.

Finally, configure your Jenkins job to run the `mvn install` command and set up the HTML Publisher as an after build task. Basically, you tell Jenkins to read the jacoco report and show it.

[image: HTML Publisher configuration]

Another detail is that you need to run Jenkins using the command below to avoid [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446279/jenkins-html-publisher-plugin-allow-script-permission-issue) when visualizing the report.

```
java -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src *;"  -jar jenkins.war
```

The final report will be like this:

[image: jacoco report]